# django forms instance

Tags: django, forms, instance

i have a method where i am saving the data from users, but each user has to have a single profile, so each time he saves, the data should be overwritten.
first i verify if he already has a profile data, and in this case i add an instance to the form. if not, (this is his first registration), i simply add data into DB
my code is: 
but i get an error:'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'
is my method right? thanks!

def save_userprofile(request):

```
   if request.method == 'POST':
        u = UserProfile.objects.filter(created_by = request.user)
        if u:

             form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=u ) 
        else:
             form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're expecting just one object back from a query, you should use the [get()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#id5) method.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
try:
    u = UserProfile.objects.get(created_by = request.user)
    # can update here
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    # create object
```

The [queryset reference](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#ref-models-querysets) should explain all. You may also find [get_or_create()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create-kwargs) is useful.

Answer (score 1):

The `instance` argument of `UserProfileForm` doesn't expect to receive a `QuerySet`, which is what you're giving it. To retrive the profile, you should use this, which returns a single `UserProfile` object:

```
u = UserProfile.objects.get(created_by = request.user)
```